# Get the average of two neighboring elements in an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to get the average of two neighboring elements in an array (x) and store these into a new array (m).

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim x = {0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0}

    Dim m() As Double = New Double() {14}

    For i = 0 To x.Length - 1
        m(i) = (x(i) + x(i + 1)) / 2
    Next
    For Each d As Double In m
        Console.WriteLine(d)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

End Module
```

I get the error

> Index is outside the bounds of the array

for the m array, however I can't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have the problem that m is only 1 item in length. You should initialize an array with more items.

```
Dim m(14) As Double
```

I highly suggest you learn about breakpoint and debugging. Also, write very small piece of your code at a time and test it. Don't try to write the whole program right from the start.

Answer (score 2):

The index starts at 0 and ends at Length - 1. The index i+1 at the end of the loop will equal the length, so it will be out of bounds.

For example for 
    Dim x = {1,2,3,4}
the index will range from 0 to 3.

Comment: Exactly, just do: For i = 0 To x.Length - 2